# Implement if else in a Button while clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, android-button

I am new to Android app development. I am developing an app with two activities. Users can jump from `MainActivity` to `Activity2` by entering some text and clicking a button. Fortunately, I have done that. But I was expecting if the user had not entered any text, it would show a toast **"You have not entered anything"** & definitely the Button click event will not happen in that case. What is the way to implement this feature using if-else?

Here's my `MainActivity.kt`

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var nameInput : EditText
    lateinit var sorryButton : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        nameInput = findViewById(R.id.nameInput)
        sorryButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_sorry)



        sorryButton.setOnClickListener {
            

            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()
            intent.putExtra("name",name)
            startActivity(intent)





        }
    }



}
```

If knows how to implement this please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put an if statement in the click listener. Make checking if the name is empty the conditional.

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {
    val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        // show toast
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("name",name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: what if, user put  "text1, text2, text3"  then `Activity2`  will open & if "Entered any other text" then `Activity3` will open ?

Comment: I think you need to read through the Kotlin language documentation. Otherwise people will endlessly be answering your specific questions without you really learning how the basic syntax and logic work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sorryButton.setOnClickListener {
     
                if(nameInput.text?.isBlank() == true) Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                else{      
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
                val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()
                intent.putExtra("name",name)
                startActivity(intent)
               }
    
    }
```

I hope this solves your query.

Comment: what if, user put "text1, text2, text3" then Activity2 will open & if "Entered any other text" then Activity3 will open ?

Comment: Your main aim is to get the text entered by the user, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, on clicking the button, you take the input and validate it. If it's not empty, you have to move to other screen.

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {
    val name: String = nameInput.text?.toString()
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You have not entered anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("name",name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

This will work as expected.

**what if, user put "text1, text2, text3" then Activity2 will open & if "Entered any other text" then Activity3 will open ?**

In this case, just add another `else if` condition in `OnClickListener`:

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {
    val name: String = nameInput.text?.toString()
    if (name.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You have not entered anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if(name == "text1, text2, text3"){
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("name",name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }else {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("name",name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **java** use this cod

```
  Button sorryButton;
  EditText nameInput;
  sorryButton = findViewById(R.id.sorryButtonId);
  nameInput = findViewById(R.id.nameInputId);
  sorryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = nameInput.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameInput.toString())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have not entered anything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else {
                startActivity(new Intent(this , Activity2.class).putExtra("NAME" , name));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want set minimum length 4 of text then use-

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

        if (name.length < 4 ) {
            nameInput.setError("Name less than 4 letters not allow")
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", name)
            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
```

Suppose if you do not allow empty then use -

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            nameInput.setError("Username required")
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", name)
            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
```

If you do not allow space between text/name then -

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

        if (name.contains(" ")) {
            nameInput.setError("Space not allow here")
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", name)
            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
```

If you want to combine all of these -

```
sorryButton.setOnClickListener {

        val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

        if (name.contains(" ") || name.length < 4 || name.isEmpty()) {
            nameInput.setError("Username required")
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", name)
            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
```

[image]